# How to use a MarkLogic DataHub importFlow from inside another database

Tags: marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

I have a usecase that needs to query some data in one database and then use this data as a new input into the MarkLogic DataHub pipeline.

I created a working import and harmonization flow.

Now I want to run the import flow from another database to insert data into th staging database in the dhf.

```
'use strict';

let id= "/ClueyTest/track/cluey/a2c5c32c-6e99-47c9-8b4d-5b97897509f7.json";

let options = {"dhf.projectName":"ClueyTest", "entity":"Track", "flow":"ImportClueyTracks", "flowType":"input", "dataFormat":"json"};

let rawContent = {
"trackId": "a2c5c32c-6e99-47c9-8b4d-5b97897509f7", 
"type": "Feature", 
"geometry": {
"type": "LineString", 
"coordinates": [
[5.4701967, 51.8190698], 
[5.470028, 51.8193624],
[5.470038, 51.8193624], 
[5.470048, 51.8193624], 
[5.470028, 51.8193634]]
}
, 
"properties": {
"timestamps": [
"2019-02-14T16:52:06+0100", 
"2019-02-14T16:51:07+0100", 
"2019-02-14T16:43:24+0100", 
"2019-02-14T16:43:24+0100", 
"2019-02-14T16:43:24+0100" 
]
}
, 
"tracktype": "on", 
"endTimestamp": "2019-02-14T16:51:07+0100", 
"startTimestamp": "2019-02-14T14:46:50+0100"
}

const clt = require('/entities/clueyTrack/input/ImportClueyTracks/main.sjs');

// the main in the import flow
clt.main(id,rawContent,options);
```

Obviously you need a working importflow inside your datahub to run this code but the question is about the general usecase how to run an import flow not from gradle but from inside a marklogic database.

All dhf code is sjs.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the Server-Side Library would be most elegant, but I think it does require DataHub v4+:

https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/refs/server-side-library/

HTH!